# Append img tag with src from a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying fetch to add an image from a Javascript Object and wrap it in an img tag - how do I do this correctly? Adding just img as an element doesn't work so whats the best way to do this?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hszxbmrx/6/

Javascript Object:

```
var retailerData = {
"del": {
    "zip": "",
    "city": ""
},
"user": {
    "country": "",
    "phone": "",
    "nbrOrders": 0,
    "name": "",
    "salesPerson": "",
    "customerNo": "",
    "email": ""
},
"order": {
    "shippingSum": 0.0,
    "orderno": "0",
    "voucher": "",
    "currency": "SEK",
    "orderVat": 3322.5,
    "orderSum": 13290.0,
    "items": [{
        "qtyAvail": 0,
  "imageURI":"http://www.windowspasswordsreset.com/windows-password-knowledge/images/dell-laptop.jpg",
        "price": 6295.0,
        "qty": 1,
  "id":"244992",
        "artno": "DEL-17812033.10-4",
        "label": "E7240&#x2F;i5-4310U&#x2F;4GB1&#x2F;128SSD&#x2F;12,5HD&#40;1366x768&#41;&#x2F;W7P 3-Cell&#x2F;CAM&#x2F;3YRNBD&#x2F;W8.1P&#x2F;US int Keyboard",
        "category": "Computers - Notebooks",
        "manufacturer": "Dell"
    }, {
        "qtyAvail": 31,
  "imageURI":"http://www.windowspasswordsreset.com/windows-password-knowledge/images/dell-laptop.jpg",
        "price": 6995.0,
        "qty": 1,
        "artno": "20BV001KUK",
        "label": "Lenovo ThinkPad T450 20BV - 14&#34; - Core i3 5010U - 4 GB RAM - 500 GB Hybrid Drive",
        "category": "Computers - Notebooks",
        "manufacturer": "Lenovo"
    }]
 }
}
```

Script:

```
$.each(retailerData.order.items,function(i,v){//get the item 
var div = $('<div class="test">') 
div.append('item '+ '<img>'+ v.imageURI+'</img>' + '<span       class="art">'+ v.artno+'</span>' + '<span class="price">'+ v.price+'</span>' ) 
$('.carttable').append(div) 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL of the `<img />` should be placed in the `src` property, and the element is self closing; it does not have a separate closing tag. Try this:

```
div.append('item <img src="' + v.imageURI + '" /><span class="art">' + v.artno + '</span><span class="price">' + v.price + '</span>')
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hszxbmrx/8/)

Also note that you don't need to append string literals together, you can just use a single string.

Comment: The spec's term for elements like `img` is [void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). In HTML, the `/` before the `>` is completely optional. (It would be required in XHTML.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, that part is personal preference. Either way, using `<img>http://foo.com/bar.jpg</img>` is incorrect.